# mysql insert set problem

Tags: sql

I need some help.

```
set = {0, 0};
Print[set];
Needs["DatabaseLink`"];
JDBCDrivers["MySQL(Connector/J)"]
conn = OpenSQLConnection[
         JDBC["MySQL(Connector/J)", "localhost:3306/test"], 
        "Username" -> "root", "Password" -> "root"]
SQLExecute[conn, "INSERT INTO numbers VALUES ([set]) "]
```

I don't know know how to escape `[set]` in the insert statement

In the database the field type is text

Comment: set = {11, 2, 3}; -> i have modified as you suggested, now the problem is that only the first number 11 of the set is inserted -> SQLExecute[conn, "INSERT INTO numbers (text) VALUES (`1`) ", set]

Comment: i want to put the entire set in one field of the db table, not one colum -> one element of set / from doc : SQLExecute[conn, "INSERT INTO TEST (X,Y) VALUES (`1`, `2`)", {5, 2.1}] it's my first time using mathematica

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
set = {{0, 0},{1,1},{2,2}}
SQLExecute[conn,"INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (?,?)", set]
```

If you want to do just one case, use:

```
 set = {{0, 0}}
```

The `?` way is the fast one.

You can lear a lot in the [Database Link User Guide Tutorial](http://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/DatabaseLinkUserGuide/) that is a nice official material from Wolfram. You can download the pdf for free.

Comment: how can i put the entire set as "{{0, 0},{1,1},{2,2}}" in one field in the db with brackets so when i make a select the result returned to be -> {{0, 0},{1,1},{2,2}} ?

Comment: SQLExecute[conn,"INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (?,?)", set]

Comment: so i'm trying to reformulate, i have set = {{0, 0},{1,1},{2,2}} and a table with 3 fileds text1, text2, text3 , how can i put in the db the folwooing text1 -> {0, 0} , text2 -> {1, 1}, text3 -> {3, 3} ?

Comment: @user5356 You can handle it as a string, and use `ToExpression` to back it to MMA form again, like: `ToExpression["{0,0}"]` you get {0,0}

Comment: can you pls modify the query with ToExpression because i don't understand how to do that , tx